# default to floats in python

Tags: python, floating-point, int, dronekit-python

I'm writing some code that uses GPS coordinates but I'm running into a headache with python 2. I'm using the dronekit python library to be specific. Here's a sample of what I'm trying to do.

```
current_location = LocationGlobalRelative(x,y)
dx = get_change_x(params) # float value to change x coordinate
dy = get_change_y(params) # float value to change y coordinate
new_x = current_location.lon + dx 
new_y = current_location.lat + dy
print new_x
print new_y
```

The issue is that new_x and new_y print rounded values such as 41.0. I know the issue can be corrected by wrapping the numbers with float() but this seems really clunky. Is there a way to tell python that all numbers should be treated as floats?

Comment: What does `type(current_location.lat)` give you? It's possibly something that acts like but isn't quite a float. The fact that `print new_x` shows a ".0" suggests that it is a float, just rounded.

Comment: For that matter, what are `dx` and `dy` here, too?

Comment: If any of the numbers are `floats` then the adding `int` values will coerce them to `floats` as well.  Can you provide some additional tests of each of the variables?

Comment: dcrosta, current_location.lat gives a float. dx and dy are also floats